# How to not listen last emitted value of Subject when new component is loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have one subject  which I am listening on two different routes.In a route I am setting that subject value and  also listening that. From that route after setting its subject value navigate to other route where I am listening same subject on ngOnInit().
that route is listened last emitted value from previous route url, Is there any way to handle that  I can not listen last emmited value.Only listen when component is loaded

Comment: Sounds like the first() operator can help you: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/first

Comment: You could use `skip(1)`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am looking into these operators

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `BehaviorSubject` this is the reason why you are seeing this behavior, when you subscribe to a BehaviorSubject this will emit the last value.
Instead of that, you need to use a normal Subject this will emit a value when the subject execute a next method.

Comment: I am using Subject

Comment: Can you show us the code? And when you fired a new value when that component is mounting?

Comment: Its to long and too many things to explain